# Java swap characters but not vowels

Tags: java, swap

I want to swap the characters in the string except for vowels. There is plenty of code out there, however, this is the one I am working upon, I find it easy to understand but this is not producing the outcome as expected.

```
public class RandomPractise {

    //1st find out a vowel
    public Boolean isVowel(char c) {
        boolean isV = true;
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
            isV = true;
        } else {
            isV = false;
        }
        return isV;
    }

    //Check current and next chars if not vowel do the swap
    public void randomTest() {
        String str = "boat";

        char[] c1 = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < c1.length - 1; i++) {
            if (!(isVowel(c1[i])) && !(isVowel(c1[i + 1]))) {
                char temp = c1[i];
                c1[i] = c1[i + 1];
                c1[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(c1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomPractise r = new RandomPractise();
        r.randomTest();
    }
```

Sample: If I use input: boat I expect to see output: toab [this does not happen]. When I use input: sboath I see output bsoaht.

Question: What change should I do to make it work for boat?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: 'sb' is swapped to 'bs' in '[sb]oath' because the 's' is next to 'b'. In the word 'boat' you have no consonants next to each other: 'bo' is a pair of consonant-vowel, 'oa' is vowel-vowel, and 'at' is vowel-consonant. Your program only swaps pairs of consonants, there is no such pair.

Comment: What do you expect to get with a word like  `elect`.  And what is the rule to follow?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Question: What change should I do to make it work for boat?"

do you mean to do this?

```
public class RandomPractise {

    //1st find out a vowel
    public Boolean isVowel(char c) {
        boolean isV = true;
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
            isV = true;
        } else {
            isV = false;
        }
        return isV;
    }

    public void randomTest() {
        String str = "boat";

        char[] c1 = str.toCharArray();
        int n = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
            if (!(isVowel(c1[i])) && !(isVowel(c1[n - i - 1]))) {
                char temp = c1[i];
                c1[i] = c1[n - i - 1];
                c1[n - i - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(c1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomPractise r = new RandomPractise();
        r.randomTest();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Thank You.

Comment: Can you please explain !(isVowel(c1[n - i - 1]))) this part? I have to wait 4 minutes before I can accept.

Comment: @SheikhRahman actually it is a trick to get the just opposite symmetric character in string, for ex if you have a string of length 7, then if you are at index 0, then you will get (n - i - 1) as 6, if you are index 1 , then (n - 1 - i) will get you 5, if at 2, then (n - 1 - i) will get you 4, if you are at index 3, then (n - 1 - i) will get you 3, it is a standard trick to reverse a string quickly. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong I checked the above program for the string ```abcde``` its printed  ```adcbe```  which is not correct but it should be ```acbde```

Comment: @rahulsharma I just understood what OP wanted by the description of question he wrote. see boat example and then after I answered the question, op confirmed that this is what he wanted, so answer of abcde should be "adcbe" not "acbde" according to OP requirement, even though I agree, that the way OP mentioned the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @mss there is gap in the understanding of OP and without even check the program for other inputs he just the accepted the answer which is not a correct! whenever we are writing a program it should be able to accept the other input not just passed by someone . Thanks

Comment: @rahulsharma OP asked me what does c1[n  - i - 1] does, and I explained him what it does, and I also asked if it is not clear. I provided my solution by confirming the answers on different input(it should be obvious). It's OP wish to accept the answer just after checking one input or after confirming different input, but  again as long as atleast one person who answers or person who ask question is careful about answer, there is a high probability that answer should be correct.

Comment: @mss are you saying that this answer is correct for all the input ?? not What OP says forget about him

Comment: @rahulsharma OP himself said, this is what he wanted. If he didn't want this why would he accept the answer in first place, yes this answer is correct.

Comment: you're not getting me what I mentioned that forget about the OP what he says just tell me one thing is this program run for every input correctly

Comment: @rahulsharma yes, try it.

Comment: I have already shared you the input and output previously! ok before you say anything tell me what is swapping the non-vowels in string what is your understanding

Comment: @rahulsharma because you didn't understand what OP wanted as expected answer, see my above talk with OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214338/discussion-between-mss-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: @mess I do understand that what OP wanted but we should answer in such way that it should run for every input and output as expected what the question says that being said that there is possibility that he has missed the concept and accepted the answer in hurry .